# Do jQuery events on object elements work?

Tags: jquery, events, object

I haven't been able to successfully attach a jQuery event listener onto an element of type `<object>`, and get it to pick up any events that are triggered on that event.

Thus:

```
<object></object>
```

With JavaScript:

```
$('object').on('foo', function(evt, data){ alert(data) });
$('object').trigger('foo', 'object-on-object');
```

If I have the exact same code on `$('body')`, then it works fine. Also, If I listen for events on `<body>`, and `$('object').trigger()`, then I do get the event.

I have a [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/bxnKR/1/) that demonstrates this. In it you will see that the `bar` event has caused no output, but the two `foo` events have.

Comment: Lol and a magic here: works with `.live` which is deprecated: http://jsfiddle.net/vNqZD/1/ **But** not to worry I am looking into this will flick you an update soon :P I am on osx safari and can see your issue man - interesting - I bet it is going to be tiny lil solution.

Comment: @Tats_innit: well, that is interesting. I didn't think to try out a deprecated function. I'll have a look at the jQuery source, too.

Comment: @MatthewSchinckel lol it is I am reading it now B-) there should be something very small reason why.

Comment: Equivalent syntax of `$.live` with `$.on` works too. [FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/joycse06/vNqZD/4/)

Comment: @Joy nopes you missed a point `$(document).` we want OPs code i.e. `('object').on` B-)

Comment: Yeah, I know, but to make it work like `$.live` have to bind the event to a `parent`. Thats why i did it.

Comment: And as you know, `$.live` itself uses `$.on` to bind the event into a parent. Here is the line from jQuery source of `$.live`
`jQuery( this.context ).on( types, this.selector, data, fn );` I am not sure what `this.context` is here. But it must will be a parent of `object` in this case.

Comment: Bruv - I went in circles, the only way it works is using deprecated `.live` see here: http://groups.google.com/group/jquery-dev/browse_thread/thread/8fbbd73d142dad78/82759f4dd14936e9?#82759f4dd14936e9 Will give you further read on the current issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, it seems like the answer is no. According to [this thread](http://groups.google.com/group/jquery-dev/browse_thread/thread/8fbbd73d142dad78/82759f4dd14936e9?#82759f4dd14936e9), there are issues related to binding events, or perhaps doing anything interesting with jQuery and `<object>` elements.

The solution, it seems, is to let the events bubble up elsewhere. `$(document)` seems to be a valid choice, so you can do things like:

```
$(document).on('foo', 'object', {data: data}, handler);

$('object').trigger('foo');
```

This is kind of the wrong way for what I wanted (I wanted to be able to tell consumers to listen to events on a plugin element), but it works well enough. What you can't fix in code, fix in documentation.